# Why document.execCommand not working in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wysiwyg

**I am trying to create simple wysiwyg editor in my react projects** but not working `document.execCommand` ,

I am referring [codepen](https://codepen.io/trhino/pen/xyLAu) (They used jQuery library here for click function)

Any possible to create simple wysiwyg editor in reactjs ?

```
//document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {});

    const wrapTag = (role) => {
        switch(role) {
            case 'h1':
            case 'h2':
            case 'p':
              document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, role);
              break;
            default:
              document.execCommand(role, false, null);
              break;
          }
    }

    <div onClick={ () => { wrapTag("bold") } }>bold</div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet saepe nostrum aspernatur deserunt rem neque ab.</p>
```

Comment: problem is with click you are loosing focus and putting the focus on the button.

Comment: I tried with pure javascript click document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {}); but not luck , could you show me code brother ? @epascarello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an `event.preventDefault`, to keep the focus:

```
    const wrapTag = (role) => {
        document.designMode = "on"
        switch(role) {
            case 'h1':
            case 'h2':
            case 'p':
              document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, role);
              break;
            default:
              document.execCommand(role, false, null);
              break;
          }
    }

    <div onClick={ () => wrapTag("bold") } onMouseDown={(event) => 
        event.preventDefault()}>bold</div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet saepe nostrum aspernatur deserunt rem neque ab.</p>
```

Comment: I tried your code but not calling this function when I add (role) => (event)  .. @Adam

Comment: You also have to change the ```onClick={ wrapTag("bold") }```, so the `wrapTag` can recieve the event

Comment: Click Fn worked but not worked script , when I click bold button selection removing, that means html re rendering ?

Comment: Changed my answer, how about now?

Comment: Improved , not worked as we expected,  didnt remove selection when i click button

Comment: Based on the [execCommand api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) you should also set `document.designMode = "on"`